# PowerBI Problems Subtracting Rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

Ok, so I'm trying to take two rows and subtract them to make another column with that difference. I know that there is a Question like this already but it need more help. here is the code that I think would work.

=Table.AddColumn(#"YourLastStep", "Diff",
each
(try DateTime.From(#"YourLastStep"[Time]{[ID]-2})
otherwise DateTime.From([Time])) - [Time]
)

But I don't understand "=Table.AddColumn(#"YourLastStep", "Diff",
each." what does "YourLastStep" mean please help.

Thank you,

Comment: To clarify what I'm looking for, I have rows of data that have a status column and a date/time that the status is entered. When filtering by user, If the status is entered as "D", that user is indicating they are beginning a task. Once the task is complete, they change the status to "On", which not a unique status for this task, but does give the date/time the status is entered. 

The row with the "On" status follows immediately after the row with the "D" status, and I need to find the time difference between the two for every status of D on the table.

Answer (score 0):

If I take the following

```
    let
    Source = {1..10},
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

In `#"Changed Type"` step, `YourLastStep` is `#"Converted to Table"`

In `#"Converted to Table"` step,  `YourLastStep` is `Source`